# how to get class name of all tags of json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON data and i want to list all attributes of class name inside divs and inner divs and tags.

Sample JSON DATA :

```
[
  {
    "Field1": "<header class=\"main-header dark-bg\">\n\t\t<div class=\"row\">\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"col-xl-3\">\n<a class=\"icons-darkbg-slogan main-header__slogan\" data-event_engagement=\"\" data-event_linktype=\"internal page link\" data-event_source=\"DAM|active|de|de|/\" data-event_target=\"/\" data-event_title=\"Header Home::Slogan\" href=\"/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"DWS Homepage\"><img src=\"/globalassets/images/logos/dws_logo_global.svg\" class=\"icon-svg hide-for-print\" alt=\"dws_logo_global\"></a>\n\t\t</div>\n\n\t\t<div class=\"space-9 hide-md\"></div>\n\t</header>"
  }
]
```

I have used children() but it is not taking inner class name, output i got is
main-header dark-bg row space-9 hide-md using the below code by taking json data in a variable

```
if($(t).children().length > 0){
console.log($(t).children().length);
//OUTPUT SHOWING 2
}
```

Comment: So for all the HTML elements in your JSON string, you want to know the value of the class attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use some relatively straightforward recursion to traverse down the DOM tree within the HTML string, something like this:

```js
var data = [{
  "Field1": "<header class=\"main-header dark-bg\">\n\t\t<div class=\"row\">\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"col-xl-3\">\n<a class=\"icons-darkbg-slogan main-header__slogan\" data-event_engagement=\"\" data-event_linktype=\"internal page link\" data-event_source=\"DAM|active|de|de|/\" data-event_target=\"/\" data-event_title=\"Header Home::Slogan\" href=\"/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"DWS Homepage\"><img src=\"/globalassets/images/logos/dws_logo_global.svg\" class=\"icon-svg hide-for-print\" alt=\"dws_logo_global\"></a>\n\t\t</div>\n\n\t\t<div class=\"space-9 hide-md\"></div>\n\t</header>"
}]

function buildClassArray($el, arr) {
  arr = arr || [];
  $el.each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).prop('class'));
    $(this).children().each(function() {
      buildClassArray($(this), arr);
    })
  });  
  return arr;
}

var classes = buildClassArray($(data[0].Field1));
console.log(classes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that if you want multiple classes on a single element to appear within their own entity in the array, simply `split()` the class string before you push it to the array:

```js
var data = [{
  "Field1": "<header class=\"main-header dark-bg\">\n\t\t<div class=\"row\">\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"col-xl-3\">\n<a class=\"icons-darkbg-slogan main-header__slogan\" data-event_engagement=\"\" data-event_linktype=\"internal page link\" data-event_source=\"DAM|active|de|de|/\" data-event_target=\"/\" data-event_title=\"Header Home::Slogan\" href=\"/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"DWS Homepage\"><img src=\"/globalassets/images/logos/dws_logo_global.svg\" class=\"icon-svg hide-for-print\" alt=\"dws_logo_global\"></a>\n\t\t</div>\n\n\t\t<div class=\"space-9 hide-md\"></div>\n\t</header>"
}]

function buildClassArray($el, arr) {
  arr = arr || [];
  $el.each(function() {
    arr.push(...$(this).prop('class').split(' '));
    $(this).children().each(function() {
      buildClassArray($(this), arr);
    })
  });  
  return arr;
}
var $el = $(data[0].Field1);
var classes = buildClassArray($el);
console.log(classes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, It Worked for me !

Comment: No problem, glad to help